# Inserting associative array in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array which include name and id , I want to insert these things into the table but I am only being able to insert the four rows out of 11 rows 
I don't know where I committed the mistake ,

This is my array :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 6143310130 [name] => ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 3310773561 [name] => Arau ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 1127328875 [name] => Womens  )
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 9847224704 [name] => shoulder ) 
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 7099570428 [name] => Swapna )
    [5] => Array ( [id] => 5263908918 [name] => Top Hospitals India )
    [6] => Array ( [id] => 7504483424 [name] => Wodsjls ) 
    [7] => Array ( [id] => 2051860883 [name] => Star ) 
    [8] => Array ( [id] => 4582742687 [name] => Manipal chand ) 
    [9] => Array ( [id] => 1024875457 [name] => lokpal ) 
    [10] => Array ( [id] => 7120814620 [name] => Shiney ) 
    [11] => Array ( [id] => 8367976928 [name] => suma )
)
```

My sql query is as follows :

```
foreach ($ret as  $key) {   
    if(mysqli_query($con,"insert ignore INTO AdsAccount(accountID,accountName) VALUES ('$key[id]','$key[name]')")) {
        echo "success";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you using primary key or unique key in your table? If possible please add your table schema.

Comment: primary key as a account id

Comment: Please check if any of the account id you are trying to insert already exist or not.

Comment: No,it's not existed any where in the table,i.e why I put insert ingnore into adsaccount as a query

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: Put an else in your if statement and add the following code `mysqli_error($con)` to find out if there are any eventual errors with the connection

Comment: Can you please post the result of `SELECT * FROM AdsAccount;`  and `SHOW CREATE TABLE AdsAccount`?

Comment: what is the length of your primary key (id) field? Try to follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that everybody who is trying to help _you_ doesn't have to go through a long questionnaire to figure out something that makes sense.

Comment: @KiranKumar What about my answer? It would be nice if you up-vote my answer and mark it as accepted. Or comment the answer, if you have further trouble .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is an typo in your SQL syntax. Define SQL query string in a variable as follows, without 'ignore' (the ignore statement supresses errors):

```
$sql = 'insert INTO AdsAccount(accountID,accountName) VALUES ('.$key[id].','.$key[name].')';
```

Use a loop to create the query for the insertions:

```
$i = 0;
$sql = 'insert INTO AdsAccount(accountID,accountName) VALUES';
foreach($array as $key) {
    $sql .= '('.$key['id'].','.$key['name'].')';
    if($i < count($array) - 1) {
        $sql .= ",\n";
    }
    $i++;
}
$sql .= ';';
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

May you have to split your query, because only four inserts are possible at the same time. Use the modulus operation in this case.

EDIT:
An even better way for doing that is to use prepared statements from the PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension.

For this you need a PDO connection

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=<dbhost>;dbname=<dbname>', <dbuser>, <dbuserpass>);
```

Then you can do the following:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO AdsAccount (accountID , accountName ) VALUES (:accountID, :accountName)");

// $id and $name work as references
$stmt->bindParam(':accountID',  $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':accountName', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

foreach($array as $key) {
    $id = $key['id']; //set the reference for id
    $name = $key['name']; //set the reference for name
    $stmt->execute(); //execute the statement
}
```

A detailed description you can find at: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: use prepared statements, damn it.

Comment: You're right, prepared statements are better! But that is not the answer to the **actual question**. Further information about prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: while prepared statements are rarely the focus of the question, querystring building is almost never the best/right path to use and showing that kind of code will reiterate the wrong usage between novice PHP developers. Please, walk one more mile and clean up the snippet. I'll be happy to upvote this answer with prepared statements.